# Organize Python package to run from its top-level directory?

Tags: python

How do I organize a Python package so its code runs from the top-level directory without adding that directory to the host's Python path?

I would also like to organize the code so I can run tests from the various test subdirectories, again without adding the package's top-level directory to the python path.

Consider the following code layout:

```
foobar/
  __init__.py
  README.txt
  its_a_module.py
  one_package/
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    bar.py
    tests/
      __init__.py
       testing_one_package.py
  tests/
    __init__.py
    test_foobar.py
```

- When in foobar/, I should be able to import foobar and all its submodules in the python interpreter
- From foobar/, I should be able to run tests/test_foobar.py.
- From foobar/tests, I should be able to run test_foobar.py
- From one_package/tests, I should be able to run testing_one_package.py.

How do I organize the import statements of my various modules, and the contents of my **init**.py files, to meet those objectives?

(I would like to use distutils to manage the code, and I read that running the code from the top-level directory is a useful precursor.)

Comment: it's perfectly unclear what is the actual problem, and what you have tried to solve it so far.

Comment: I just set `PYTHONPATH=$PWD` when I'm doing this (e.g., `PYTHONPATH=$PWD python tests/test_foobar.py`).

Comment: It's rather simple. Don't run code from inside the package, but one level up.

Comment: That makes sense but suggests that I can't meet the criteria of running tests from their test directories, at least not without messing with the paty.  Is that so?

Comment: This also raises the question of properly setting the import statements.  If testing_one_package imports foobar.its_a_module, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `..` to your `PYTHONPATH`. That will satisfy your first two conditions:

- When in foobar/, I should be able to import foobar and all its submodules in the python interpreter
- From foobar/, I should be able to run tests/test_foobar.py.

You can always import absolutely, `import foobar` and `from foobar.one_package import ...` no `import one_package` and other relative imports.  In this way you can run any submodule from the foobar dir.

For the other two stipulations,

- From foobar/tests, I should be able to run test_foobar.py
- From one_package/tests, I should be able to run testing_one_package.py.

you could add grandparents and great-grandparents of the `PWD` to the `PYTHONPATH` but I have never heard of this and it sounds bad. You can't really get around installing `foobar`, ie, putting it on your path, if you want the foobar package to be available no matter how deeply you go.

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean adding '..' explicitly to the path, or the directory string represented thereby.  If the latter, I explicitly don't want to do that, I want to be able to run the code without messing with sys.path.

Comment: `..` explicitly, the parent of the current dir.